# How to make relations in Eloquent, to count which downloads was made by which users

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I want to make the linking pivot table to link Users with Files models, and count amount of downloads, to know which User downloaded which Files.

The problem is that I don't know how to make it on Eloquent's relations level — how it should look like, when I want to ask Laravel, which Files was downloaded by User with id... 5, for example.

Please, tell me how Models and Relationships in them should look like? And how can I ask Eloquent to find out the number of downloads (and a list of Users, who downloaded a particular file).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try looking into the documentation first. www.laravel.com

Answer (score 0):

You will need downloads table(id, user_id, file_id) and module, where you list all the downloads.

Download.php

```
<?php
class Download extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'downloads';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function file()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('File', 'file_id');
    }
}
```

Than in controller use this:

```
$downloads = Download::all();
$list = [];

foreach($downloads as $download)
{
$list[$download->id]['download'] = $download;
$list[$download->id]['user'] = $download->user;
$list[$download->id]['file'] = $download->file;
}
```

For getting downloaded files from users

User.php

```
<?php
    class User extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $table = 'users';

        public function downloads()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Download', 'user_id', 'id');
        }
    }
```

In controller

```
$downloads = $user->downloads;
```

The same for files